# Тире или запятая с ним?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, бсп, запятая-и-тире

`Ни кино, ни театра, ни книг, ни газет(,) — одно сплошное телевидение!`

Нужна запятая? И если нужна, можно еë объяснить по [справочнику Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_46.htm)? На второй вопрос ответить обязательно!

Comment: *Ничего не будет: ни кино, ни театра, ни книг, ни газет — одно сплошное телевидение.*

Тексты фильмов: https://cinematext.ru/movie/moskva-slezam-ne-verit-1979/?page=5&ysclid=loiuec5q16658843721

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая не нужна:

*Ни кино, ни театра, ни книг, ни газет — **одно сплошное телевидение!***

**Пояснение**

Синтаксис нестандартный, но в любом случае это **сложное** предложение с **бессоюзной** связью.

**Содержание** такое: **нет** ничего из названного — **(а) есть** только телевидение.

По грамматике **номинативный ряд** в первой части и  **номинатив** во второй части (значение **бытия**: нет и есть)

Противопоставление обозначено **тире**, более сильного знака не нужно.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответик. А если противопоставление, всегда тире ставим?

Comment: Здесь  скорее сопоставление и противопоставление  (есть/нет) одновременно, пропуск сопоставительного союза А, а также номинативная структура предложений.  Пауза нужна обязательно, и тире самый подходящий знак.